# Ошибка в Visual Studio Code(слетели стили)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Последний раз открывал vscode несколько дней назад, сегодня открываю, а там такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные программы нормально работает. Ничего не поменял в настройке VSCode. По возможности не хочу переустановить VSCode, так как там были расширение, настройки и т.д.

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим?

Comment: Напишите им тоже самое в support, они вам подскажут явно точнее чем тут

Comment: Попытался. "Technical Support#
You can ask questions and search for answers on Stack Overflow and enter issues and feature requests directly in our GitHub repository.

If you'd like to contact a professional support engineer, you can open a ticket with the Microsoft assisted support team.

"  Перехожу по этому ссылку: https://support.microsoft.com/assistedsupportproducts  А там вечная перезагрузка, сайт техподдержки майкрасофт не знаеть что делать..

Comment: Тогда не знаю что посоветовать, я бы просто переустановил, плагины поставить 5 сек, а конфиг с настройками лично я храню в облаке, чтобы быстро развернуть среду где угодно